# Filetype of code

Tags: android, mysql, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

```
{
"id": 2,
"first_name": "Reo",
"last_name": "Urel",
"email": "rurel@tripadvisor.com",
"gender": "Female",
"ip_address": "90.167.185.138",
"photo": "http://dummyimage.com/144x152.png/ff4444/ffffff",
"employment": {
    "name": "Google",
    "position": "Support"
}
```

}

What type of file is here? And how can I realize it in sqlite filetype(there is 1000 id)?

Comment: looks like json: [google: json to sqlite](https://www.google.com/search?q=json+to+sqlite)

Comment: You can just dump JSON into a SQLite JSON-type column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is `josn` file. SQLITE filetype is `.SQLITE or .DB`.

You can convert json into SQLITE using below url :- 
https://sqlify.io/convert/json/to/sqlite